References on classical quadratic gravity
Quadratic gravity is an interesting model of modified gravity because it leads to a perturbatively renormalizable theory of quantum gravity (Stelle, K. S. Phys. Rev. D 16 (1977), 953). I know of a few references discussing aspects of the quantization of this model (such as 1804.09944 and 2112.01974), but I was wondering about whether there are any references concerning its classical aspects. In particular, whether the Cauchy problem is well-defined, occurrences of runaway solutions, and similar aspects.

Beyond my comprehension why this was closed.  It's a request for resources and in no way opinion based.  Voted to re-open.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine I also did not understand it. I added a reference to renormalizability of quadratic gravity in case people found the statement too bold (which I guess could be misinterpreted as not mainstream)

Papers by Donoghe have multiple times looked into quadratic gravity, so I would suggest looking at his references in those papers. For example, he has derived the running coupling for $\alpha(\mu)R^2$ and $\beta(\mu)R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}$, albeit, they only contain some scale set by hand and the UV-divergence (not much physics).
However, something I must mention is that when computing amplitudes that involve graviton scattering with some matter, you can never produce $R^2$ terms. So, from an effective field theory point of view, $R^2$ doesn't produce any useful physics.
